# Any tips on how I would render widgets based on phone direction?

Tags: dart, flutter

If the phone's primary direction is vertical, I want the two items to appear like in a column and if the phone's direction is horizontal, I want the two items to appear like in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MediaQuery.of(context)` will give you orientation, and more. [API docs here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html).

For example, inside of your build() method:

```
var columnCount =
          MediaQuery.of(context).orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 4;
```